# open system and other useful namespaces by default

Tags: f#

Can fsi.exe (F# interactive) have a profile. so that in the profile I can open namespaces like System by default?

today after launching fsi.exe I always have to do open System;; manually!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use

```
fsi.exe --load startupscript.fsx
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx

Comment: In addition, if you always want a certain script (or scripts) loaded into the F# interactive window in Visual Studio, you can add them by going to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `F# Tools` -> `F# Interactive` and adding the `--use` or `--load` switches there.

Answer (score 3):

startup.fs:
`open System`

**fsi --use:startup.fs**